# React JS Twitter Authentication Firebase

Tags: reactjs, twitter, firebase-authentication

I have created a Twitter authentication using Firebase in React JS. It works correctly. And I want to get user timelines, post a tweet once logged in. I am not sure how to retrieve the user timelines after the login? Any idea to get through this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to communicate with the Twitter API using the Twitter OAuth Token that firebase authentication provided after your user signs in.

Firebase Documentation for retrieving the OAuth token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login

Twitter API Documentation for making requests with their OAuth token: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request

However the firebase implementation of twitter auth only has **OAuth 1.0**. It is not recommended to use this method to authenticate requests from the browser.
https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-make-oauth-1-0a-calls-from-javascript/428